# Ignoring a value in a list search

Tags: python, list

I am using lists to store attributes and this problem cropped up when I was searching for equal items:

```
l = [['a',1,2],['b',1,2],['c',2,3],['d',1,2]]
if [any,1,2] in l:
    print ('blue')
elif [any,2,3] in l:
    print('red')
```

desired output

```
blue
```

What I want is the first value being ignored/can be any value.
I know the any function doesn't work this way but what is the correct method to doing so?

Perhaps this is more understandable

```
l = [['a',1,2],['b',1,2],['c',2,3],['d',1,2]]
for a in range(0,4):
    if [1,2] == x[1:] for x in l:
        print ('blue')
    elif [2,3] == x[1:] for x in l:
        print('red')
```

Comment: Why would your output print `blah` 3 times? It only appears once in your list.

Comment: What about the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:D actually managed to do it in one line thanks to pkacprzak.

```
l = [['a',1,2],['b',1,2],['c',2,3],['d',1,2]]
if any(True for x in l if x[1:] == [1,2]):
    print ('blue')
elif any(True for x in l if x[1:] == [2,3]):
    print('red')
```

Code works like this:

```
True for x in l
```

iterates over l (<---this is the letter L btw) and returns True if the next bit is True

```
if x[1:] == [1,2]
```

this checks all values of x except the first and returns True

```
any(...)
```

finds if any of the values returned from the bit inside the any is True

You could also return the value of the first item like so

```
[x[0] for x in l if x[1:] == [1,2]]
```

and iterate over that as well

Answer (score 0):

For filtering equal items (according to your definition) you can use list comprehension and slicing:

```
>>> lst = [['a',1,2],['b',1,2],['c',2,3],['d',1,2]]
>>> [e for e in lst if e[1:] == [1,2]]
[['a', 1, 2], ['b', 1, 2], ['d', 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

for completely generic case simply introduce some magical symbol to denote 'any' like '*' and write your own simple comparator

```
def matches(element, mask):
  for el, mask_el in zip(element, mask):
    if mask_el != '*' and el != mask_el:
      return False
  return True
```

and now you can do

```
for list_el in list:
  if matches(list_el, ['*', 1, 2]):
    print 'blah'
```

the nice thing is that it is very generic, and will work with arbitrary number of '*' in your mask.

Comment: please care to comment for the -1 vote. I would gladly update the answer if you find it invalid, but in my opinion this is exactly what OP is asking about and works for a very generic case